# Flagging own question as duplicate or deleting it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I recently asked the question [How to get signal when toggling a group?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267065/how-to-get-signal-when-toggling-a-group) where [@FranciscoRaga](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/49538/francisco-raga) kindly referred me to another post which provided an answer.

Should I mark my question as a duplicate or delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should vote to close it as a duplicate which I think should take effect immediately.

That way it becomes another signpost to the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there was a reason you did not find the other question.

So, besides what [@PolyGeo answered](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/should-i-flag-my-question-as-a-duplicate-or-delete-it/4796#4796), I suggest always try editing the duplicate question for readability and searchability (title, body and tags) if one thinks it is appropriate.

For example, usually titles starting with:

- *In QGIS plugin, ...* or
- *How do I ...*

are not the best for distinguishing content through searching.

Here is a Meta SE Q/A with hints for writing titles: [How do I write a good title?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated/2345#2345.)*

<sub>*Ironically, the title is not following its own guidelines, but it is a useful post anyway.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)